# How to enable IIS Compression in Out of Browser Lightswitch App

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch, silverlight-oob, http-compression

I have a Lightswitch OOB 2012 and would like to enable IIS 7 Compression. I followed these steps http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx and if I deploy my app in browser then I can see a massive drop in the size when using Fiddler.

However, when I run OOB the responses from the server are not compressed: the SVC requests do not have the Accept-Encoding: GZIP header.

**How can I tell the OOB Silverlight requests to use this header in Lightswitch?**

Fiddler: No compression:  (11 megs for first download)

[image]

Fiddler: After compression (running **In Browser)**:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are out of luck on this one.

When running in out of browser mode the [Silverlight WCF Data Services Client switches to using the Silverlight client HTTP implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650916%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#bkmk_outofbrowser). The Silverlight HTTP client does not support GZIP compression. There is an [feature request](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions/suggestions/908467-provide-support-for-gzip-compression-when-using-cl) for this to be changed but given the hazy future of Silverlight I don't think it is likely to happen.

Comment: Although I have not solved my problem I will award you the bounty for the most conclusive answer - ta

Answer (score 0):

To support compression for OOB Silverlight Applications, just add the following two lines to your App.xaml.cs(Constructor):

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", System.Net.Browser.WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp);
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", System.Net.Browser.WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp);
```

Comment: How do I do this in Lightswitch? ie. where do I put the code?